# Javascript change the souce of all images present inside a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a message or string  which contain both text as well as images as below.

```
var text = '<span class="user_message">hiiiiiii <img title=":benztip" src="path../files/stickers/1427956613.gif">  <img src="path../files/stickers/416397278.gif" title=":happy"></span>';
```

Before appending this to the the chat div i want to replace the src of the images to a default image.

How can i do that with Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: How are you appending that block to the div?

Comment: $("#chat_content").append(text);

Comment: I want to perform the replacement before appending to the div.

Comment: Is text merely a string? Or are you building the above at some point?

Comment: Yes its a string.Here the user has the option to allow or disallow image in the chat box.So before appending the text i have to do this.May i know the reason for negative vote.

Comment: Do you want the same image on both <img> tags?

Comment: yes.Its for all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your string into a jQuery-object and use the `.find()`-method to select the images inside the message-string:

```
var msg = '<span class="user_message">hiiiiiii<img title=":benztip" src="path../files/stickers/1427956613.gif" /><img src="path../files/stickers/416397278.gif" title=":happy" /></span>';
var $msg = $(msg);

$msg.find('img').attr('src', 'path_to_img');
$("#chat_content").append($msg);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/obpq1fpd/)**

Comment: @MauricePerry I don't get your point? `replace the image source of the images to a default image`, all image sources are getting replaced to a default image in my demo.

Comment: That chain might seem a little unclear; it finds a collection of ing elements, and changes the src attribute on all of them!

Comment: @Luke actually, it's the question that I find unclear.

Comment: @Luke In my understanding of the question OP wants to change all sources to a default one.

Comment: Yes i want to change all the image source should point to a  default image.

Comment: In that case, that deserves +1

Comment: Hi instead of appending directly  like $("#chat_content").append($msg); if i am using this  $("#chat_content").append("/n"+$msg);.It s not working.

Comment: If you want to add a break before your message you can use `.prepend()`. Have a look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrme17ez/)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in plain old JavaScript might work for you

```js
// save string to temporary element
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = '<span class="user_message">hiiiiiii <img title=":benztip" src="path../files/stickers/1427956613.gif">  <img src="path../files/stickers/416397278.gif" title=":happy"></span>';

// loop through images
var imgs = tmp.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var src = imgs[i].getAttribute("src"); // get current src
  src = "http://placehold.it/100x100"; // do something with path
  imgs[i].setAttribute("src", src); // set it
}

// output or whatever
document.writeln(tmp.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you Nenotlep.Its working 100%.empiric has given this by using jquey.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("image_id").src="default_img_name";
```

Comment: Images don't have ids, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for javascript solution, will work in older browsers too.

```
var spanNode = document.getElementById("spanId");
spanNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "Src1";
spanNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].src = "Src2";
```

You can also use For loop for tagnames if there are more than 2 images.